# problem with forge AR / VR toolkit and BIM360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-arvr

I'm trying to create a scene for Autodek forge ar / vr toolkit taking the .rvt model from BIM360.
I have already managed to create a scene and load it in unity but uploading the model manually

Comment: Can you share the HTTP requests you make when creating the scene for your model from BIM360?

Comment: I managed to create the scene by modifying a few scripts provided by Autodek on the toolkit page. The doubt I have is that I cannot correctly build an https request that generates the scene from an RVT model in bim360 without manually uploading the model to OSS

Answer (score 0):

When creating a scene for documents from BIM 360 Docs, there are a couple of things that are different compared to designs you upload manually:

1. The access token you use when communicating with the AR/VR Toolkit server must be "3-legged", i.e., obtained from the user login workflow.
2. When creating the AR/VR scene, you need to specify the BIM 360-specific information (like project ID or document version ID) in the `prj` property as well: https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/1.2.1#/ARVR-Toolkit/create_scene.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the idea of ​​the project is for a team to work with bim360 and create different versions and always show the latest version in unity.